# RecyclerView Item Click Listener

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to replace a ListView with a RecyclerView. The click listeners I had set up for it look like this (this is from the Activity):

```
//Road Trip selection
    roadTripList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            RoadTrip trip = trips.get(i);
            Intent intent= new Intent(RoadTripListActivity.this, RoadTripActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("startLocation", trip.getStart());
            intent.putExtra("endLocation", trip.getEnd());
            intent.putExtra("routeType", trip.getType());

            setResult(RoadTripActivity.ROADTRIP_LIST_INTENT_RESULT, intent);
            finish();

            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_right, R.anim.out_left);
        }
    });

    //Road Trip deletion
    roadTripList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(RoadTripListActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Delete this Road Trip?")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this road trip from your saved trips?")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            trips.remove(i);
                            tripStrings.remove(i);
                            tinyDB.putListString("roadtrips", tripStrings);

                            //roadTripList.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.updateAdapter(trips);
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .create().show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Adapter looks like this:

```
public class RoadTripListAdapter extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<RoadTripListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

protected ArrayList<RoadTrip> trips;
protected Context context;

public RoadTripListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RoadTrip> trips) {
    this.context = context;
    this.trips = trips;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView startTextView;
    private final TextView endTextView;
    private final ImageView imageView;
    private final LinearLayout itemLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        startTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.roadtrip_list_start);
        endTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.roadtrip_list_end);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.roadtrip_list_icon);
        itemLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.roadtrip_list_item_layout);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Get the corresponding step
    final RoadTrip trip = trips.get(position);

    holder.startTextView.setText(trip.getStart());
    holder.endTextView.setText(trip.getEnd());

    if (trip.getType().equals(SearchType.walking.name())) {
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_directions_walk_24dp));
    } else {
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_directions_car_24dp));
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return trips.size();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.road_trip_list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

public void updateAdapter(ArrayList<RoadTrip> trips) {
    this.trips = trips;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

And the list item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/roadtrip_list_item_layout"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/roadtrip_list_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_car_24dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/roadtrip_list_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="Start: "/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/roadtrip_list_end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="End: "/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I set up the equivalent for a RecyclerView? Everything I can find on the subject says to set it up inside the adapter, but that won't work in this case... Is there a way to set it up in the Activity?

Comment: You can pass listener out of custom adapter. However putting listener in adapter is not a good solution. Better in viewholder. This way you avoid leaks. This is my opinion.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? That doesn't really help me...

Also why was this downvoted??

Comment: Please post your RecyclerView Adapter code  and the list item  xml.

Comment: added them to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
((Activity) context).setResult(RoadTripActivity.ROADTRIP_LIST_INTENT_RESULT, intent);
            ((Activity) context).finish();

            ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_right, R.anim.out_left);
```

I had been using getApplicationContext to pass as the context for the adapter, so I changed it to

```
adapter = new RoadTripListAdapter(this, trips);
```

in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

In `onBindViewHolder`, add `OnClickListener` and `OnLongClickListener` like this :

```
itemLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

            RoadTrip trip = trips.get(position);
            Intent intent= new Intent(RoadTripListActivity.this, RoadTripActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("startLocation", trip.getStart());
            intent.putExtra("endLocation", trip.getEnd());
            intent.putExtra("routeType", trip.getType());

            setResult(RoadTripActivity.ROADTRIP_LIST_INTENT_RESULT, intent);
            finish();

            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_right, R.anim.out_left);
        }
    });

    //Road Trip deletion
    itemLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(RoadTripListActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Delete this Road Trip?")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this road trip from your saved trips?")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            trips.remove(position);
                            tripStrings.remove(position);
                            tinyDB.putListString("roadtrips", tripStrings);

                             notifyItemRemoved(position);
                             notifyItemRangeChanged(position, trips.size());
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .create().show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: setResult() and finish() are undefined in this case. Is this assuming the adapter is defined within the activity? That's why I said I didn't think it would work in the adapter (otherwise).

Comment: For that you can pass the Activity instance while instantiating your adapter and use it to call setResult() and finish().

Answer (score 0):

```
out_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/txtProgress"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:progress="50"
                android:progressTint="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Progress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>  

Java
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer and include explanation how/why this code solves issue?

Comment: Its Right Answere Please check this code and give a feedback